# What is Wix repeater equivalent for WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, repeater, velo

I need to create a repeater for my word press like repeater feature which is in Wix, but i don't know what is equivalent of repeater for word press.

my you help me?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand wordpress, there is no simple equivalent.

A repeater is a means to show a subset of content from one collection on a page, be it a static page or a dynamic page (the equivalent of a post page on WP).

I think the way to get equivalent functionality on WP will be to code (PHP and Query) a repeating list of items on a page or post page, setting the right PHP, HTML structure, CSS and Query structure for what you wanna achieve.

Maybe there is a plugin that can automate that for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stein Asmul,
i'm new in wordpress and coding, Do you know which plugin is more similar to wix repeater? or other one which connect to database automatically?
thanks a lot ;)